Verifying idToken and authorizationCode in Nodejs with Apple
After a series of operations, the client side sends me the identityToken and authorizationCode for Apple. I verify idToken according to kid as in the code snippet below.
async appleLogin(appleLoginDto: AppleLoginDto) {
    const id_token = appleLoginDto.id_token;
    const { header } = jwt.decode(id_token, {
      complete: true,
    });
    const kid = header.kid;
    const publicKey = (await this.key(kid)).getPublicKey();
    console.log(publicKey);
    const test = jwt.verify(id_token, publicKey);
    return test
  }

  async key(kid) {
    const client = jwksClient({
      jwksUri: 'https://appleid.apple.com/auth/keys',
      timeout: 30000,
    });

    return await client.getSigningKey(kid);
  }

But I think this verification is not enough. How can I use the Authorization Code, match it with this jwt content and provide secure login?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/generate_and_validate_tokens
